# Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 14.04.2 fails with error Entrust Certification Authority - L1K SSL Error 61

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, ssl, citrix

Currently I am using ubuntu 14.02.2 64 bit version.
My citrix receiver was working fine for a few months. After a few updates ubuntu fails to open the application with the following error:

```
Entrust Certification Authority -L1K, the issuer of the server's security certificate (SSL error 61).
```

I am getting this error in firefox and chrome.
I have tried copying entrust certificate L1K to `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/keystore/cacerts/` and  `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/`, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed Citrix Receiver 13.1 64 bit version and it solved the issue. We would be hitting some issues while installing it, because it has dependency in 32 bit library.  Solution is available if you google "how to run 32 bit application in 64 bit ubuntu".